# Can I have multiple root elements without HTML tags?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

We have an old ASP Classic site.  They have React added as custom features to the site, but it's not architecturally "great" since each is its own "package" and gets served as a single static JS file via IIS.

I'd like to run Next so that I can have a local dev server to run the UI elements in standalone mode, without having to build & bundle the whole ASP & IIS Server while developing.

With the most recent version of Next 13, there is a root `layout.tsx` with `RootLayout()`.  There is no more concept of `createRoot(document.getElementById(selector));`.

I have checked the docs and the Manual Installation no longer implies this is doable.  I see that you can have [multiple root layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts), however, I believe that Next still creates the `html` & `body` tag elements.

In the ASP site, we can create many options for [React to attach to](https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project#step-2-render-react-components-anywhere-on-the-page).  I am guessing this may require a lot of rolling our own to get to the same end result I am hoping to achieve with Next out of the box.

I think I can figure out how to manually generate a [static export](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports) of the complete bundle to be served by IIS

My question is:

- Does nextJS allow for a custom root node to attach to?
- If so, can I bypass Next from creating new  `html` & `body` tag elements so we can use the elements created in the legacy app?